# iTunes Connect closed this holiday?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect was closed for a week last year around the christmas holidays.

Does anyone know if there will be a similar period of time where iTunes Connect is closed this year?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? We generally close questions asking what apple plans to do since they invite guesses. Would you be amenable to editing this to ask when past announcements were made as that could actually be answers definitively yet still let people make an informed decision about how they work with the iTunes connect service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do it every year. The official announcement is too early to be. In 2011 it came on Nov 16th. I have no mail from 2012 to see when it came.